# Maximized WPF RibbonWindow Hides Windows Taskbar

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control, taskbar, maximize-window

I have a WPF RibbonWindow which defaults to maximized. The problem is that if a user has their window's taskbar autohide, once it hides, it won't come back. Hovering over the bottom of the screen doesn't seem to trigger it. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: The Telerik RadRibbonView has the same problem as Microsoft's RibbonView window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a bug in RibbonWindow (http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/634858/microsoft). I was able to fix it by changing to use a Ribbon control inside of a regular Window. However, this does mess up the taskbar for my application:

[image]

Comment: It's more of a workaround than a real fix... is there actually a way to use the RibbonView and not have this happen?